# Plot multiple catplots from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataset, jupyter

I have a dataframe and I want to plot multiple catplots. I want to use a loop but i do not know how to code one for this. Any examples?

```
{
DF = pd.DataFrame(feat[["click", "hour", "banner_pos", "site_category", "app_category"]])

sb.catplot( data =DF, y ="banner_pos", hue="click", kind = "count", palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6", height= 4)

sb.catplot( data =DF, y ="hour", hue="click", kind = "count", palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6", height= 4  )

sb.catplot( data =DF, y ="site_category", hue="click", kind = "count", palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6", height= 4  )

sb.catplot( data =DF, y ="app_category", hue="click", kind = "count", palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6", height= 4  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. It will create a separate plot for each column in your dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

columns =["click", "hour", "banner_pos", "site_category", "app_category"]

df = pd.DataFrame(feat[columns])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize = (12,7))

k:int =1
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        sns.catplot(data =df, y =columns[k], hue="click", kind = "count", palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6", height= 4, ax = ax[i,j])
        ax[i,j].set_title(f"{columns[k]}")
        k+=1
plt.tight_layout()
```